# question involving the limit of geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We have that $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is s.t. $a>1$. I was wondering what happens to the following as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

$$\frac{a^{2N-1}+a^{2N-3}+\cdots+a}{a^{2N}+a^{2N-2}+\cdots+1}x_1 + \frac{a^{2N}}{a^{2N}+a^{2N-2}+\cdots+1}x_2-\frac{a^{2N-1}}{a^{2N}+a^{2N-2}+\cdots+1}x_3+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^N a^{N+2}}{a^{2N}+a^{2N-2}+\cdots+1}x_{N}+\frac{(-1)^{N+1} a^{N+1}}{a^{2N}+a^{2N-2}+\cdots+1}x_{N+1}$$

Since $x_n$'s are parameters, I am only interested in what happens to the coefficients as $N$ gets large.

Comment: The leading term of the coefficient of $x_i$ is immediate, and the first correction term should not be hard. We can then determine the limit if the $x_i$ are bounded, but can say very little in general.

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$
\begin{align*}
a^{2 N} + a^{2 N - 2} + \ldots + 1     &= \frac{a^{2 N + 2} - 1}{a^2 - 1} \\
a^{2 N - 1} + a^{2 N - 3} + \ldots + a &= a \frac{a^{2 N} - 1}{a^2 - 1}
\end{align*}
$$
Thus the coefficient of $x_1$ is:
$$
\frac{a^{2 N - 1} + a^{2 N - 3} \ldots + a}{a^{2 N} + a^{2 N - 2} \ldots + 1}
  = \frac{a(a^{2 N} - 1)}{a^{2 N + 2} - 1}
  = \frac{a^{2 N + 3} - a}{a^{2 N} - 1}
  \sim a^{-1}
$$
The other coefficients are:
$$
\frac{(-1)^k a^{2 N - k}}{a^{2 N} + a^{2 N - 2} + \ldots + 1}
  = \frac{(-1)^k a^{2 N - k} (a^2 - 1)}{a^{2 N + 2} - 1}
  = \frac{(-1)^k (a^{2 N + 2 - k} - a^{2 N - k})}{a^{2 N + 2} - 1}
  \sim (-1)^k a^{-k}
$$
The whole expression is asymptotically $a^{-1} x_1 + \sum_{0 \le k \le N - 1} (-1)^k a^{-k} x_{k + 2}$

Comment: actually I am adding in differences of two in the numerator and denominator, so your first line might not be right.

Comment: @mathemagician, hopfully fixed now.

Comment: not really, there's a mistake in the third line. sorry :(